# Is there a way to transform a string from JSON into a DOM structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, innerhtml

**The Problem is:**

I get the following structure (generated in PHP) sent via JSON as a string.

```
<article>

<header>  
    <h2><a href="#">url</a></h2>
    <p><time datetime="2009-11-05">05 Nov 2009</time></p>
</header>

<div class="entry"> 
    <p>something</p>
    ... 
</div>

<footer>something</footer>

</article>
```

I have a list of articles on the site and I need to replace an existing article with the received one. Using jQuery, I would do something like this:

```
var $victim = $slider.find('article.loading:first'); 
    $fresh = $(basket.shift());
```

`basket.shift()` is the received article in the above string form and `$victim` is the existing one.

---

Now, normally I would do

```
$victim.replaceWith($fresh);
```

It works in good browsers (gecko, webkit) but jQuery has a known bug on using `.innerHTML` with HTML5 elements, documented [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5327). `.replaceWith` uses that method internally in the end.

---

A solution would be to use native Javascript and methods except `.innerHTML`. Something like this should work:

```
$victim.parent().get(0).insertBefore($fresh.get(0), $victim.get(0));
```

And it does, but only in good browsers, again. Something is not ok with the `.get(0)` approach on the `$fresh` var.

I've simulated an insertion of a node created locally in the js code and it works in IE:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('article');
    var dummyChild = document.createElement('header');
        txt = document.createTextNode("crap");
        dummyChild.appendChild(txt);
dummy.appendChild(dummyChild);

$victim.parent().get(0).insertBefore(dummy, $victim.get(0));
```

---

**So, is there any other way of transforming the string into a DOM subtree? Or any other way to get by the replaceWith problem?**

Note: I'm no javascript guru/ninja :)

---

Ok, after some more reading I think I've found why the `.insertBefore` doesn't work.

As the jQuery API states (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements), when I pass the `<article>` as a string, the DOM element is created also via `.innerHTML` because of its complexity.

**Is there a way to force `$()` in using the native createElement instead? I know it sucks performance-wise, but at least it will get IE working.**

Comment: I really wouldn't use the new HTML5 elements yet. It's premature: HTML5 isn't even finished yet, never mind the IE problems. The `<header>` and `<footer>` elements don't really get you anything much useful in a scripted-page context.

Comment: I'm opposed to this way of thinking :) HTML5 is ready enough for my needs. Sadly, complex situations like this fail in IE (as many other things do). I'm not using only header and footer (on the whole site), by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

You error might actually be occurring earlier than you think. When you wrap the `basket.shift()` in `$()` it is actually being added to a hidden `div` at that point. Have you tried this:

```
var $victim = $slider.find('article.loading:first'); 
    fresh = basket.shift();

$victim.replaceWith(fresh);
```

Comment: Yes, the error occurs at the `$()` function call like I said in the last edit :) Same thing happens if I give a string to `replaceWith`, it will first process the string and then replace.

Answer (score 0):

IE causes errors when working with HTML5 elements so try to donwload the script from this page and include it before any other in the head of the document:
http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/

This should prevent errors caused by HTML5 elements in IE

Comment: THe html5 shiv doesn't cover this. It just creates elements in order to enable styling. I use it by the way.